# Multipart: Unexpected end of form

Tags: express, nestjs, microservices, multipartform-data, api-gateway

I have an api gateway service that proxies requests to other microservices:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import proxy from "express-http-proxy";
import "dotenv/config";

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/api/v1/user-ms', proxy(process.env.USER_MS_URL));
app.use('/api/v1/product-ms', proxy(process.env.PRODUCT_MS_URL));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at port ${PORT}`));
```

in product-ms, I have a route that takes a picture and I send a request there via the form-data in the postman and get the following response [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi562.png)
({{API_URL}} its http://localhost:8080/api/v1)

this is what the request handler looks like:

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('picture'))
@Post()
async create(@Body() dto: any, @UploadedFile() picture) {
    console.log({picture});
    return dto;
}
```

moreover, if you do not send a request through the api gateway, but directly to the service (http://localhost:8082/product), then everything is being processed normally

I suspect this is because the api gateway sets the wrong headers.

Comment: What does the request object in the Nest server look like? Seems like either some required headers aren't being sent **or** the body is being modified

Comment: `const logReqMiddlware = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log({req});

    next();
}

app.use('/api/v1/product-ms', logReqMiddlware, proxy(process.env.PRODUCT_MS_URL));`


https://text-host.ru/bez-zagolovka-9547